# Dynamically Generate Type from Array of Enums

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build some dynamic function generator. There are a few parts.

1. An enum of function names, `FuncName`
2. An enum of input types, `InputType` with stuff like `String`, `Email`, etc.
3. A `InputMap: Record<FuncName, IInput[]>`, where `IInput` is something like `{label: string, type: InputType}`, and `InputType` is just a plain enum. `label` would be unique per input.
4. A `FuncMap: Record<FuncName, SomeFunctionType>`
5. A mapping of input types to primitives, `type InputTypeToPrimitive = {[InputType.String]: string, [InputType.Email]: string, ...}` (side-question, can I type `InputTypeToPrimitive` to force it to have all keys of `InputType` represented?)

I'm trying to type the arguments of `SomeFunctionType`. Ideally, for a given `FuncName`, the value of `SomeFunctionType` would be forced to take arguments of the corresponding `IInput`.

If I were dynamically creating the type I'd like, the JS would look like this

```
const argumentTypes = {};
InputMap[someFuncName].forEach(input => {
    argumentTypes[input.label] = InputTypeToPrimitive[input.type]
});
return argumentTypes;
```

I'm wondering if there's a clean way I can do this with typescript, such that I can type the argument of `SomeFunctionType`'s value per `FuncName`

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you've asked for but I wonder whether it solves your problem in a different way.

```
type FuncInAndOuts<T> = T extends ((...input: infer P) => infer R) ? [P, R] : never;
```

Given a function as type parameter `T`, `FuncInAndOuts<T>` returns a tuple `[P, R]` where P is the array of all of `T`'s inputs, and `R` is the function's return type.

For example given these two functions

```
// convert a number to a string
const stringify = (n: number) => '' + n

// convert n to a string and concatenate with str
const stringifyTwo = (n: number, str: string) => '' + n + str
```

`FuncInAndOuts` returns these descriptions of their inputs and outputs

```
type Stringify = FuncInAndOuts<typeof stringify>
// type Stringify = [[number], string]

type StringifyTwo = FuncInAndOuts<typeof stringifyTwo>
// type StringifyTwo = [[number, string], string]
```

Does that help you achieve what you want?